# Why do languages need libraries?

Tags: libraries

Can't the languages just include the functions in them?

For example to use the `sqrt` function in Python you need to import the **math library**.

Why can't languages already have these functions built in?

Comment: Modularization. Not everyone needs the `sqrt` function (for example), so why should they pay an eventual price of having it?

Comment: Where do you draw the line? Should every language include every possible function anyone might ever need?

Answer (score 1):

Names are a scarce resource.

Would you want to be required to avoid using **thousands** of names, including things like `max`, `set`, `read`, and `cycle`?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you have two very different questions and a very precise answer is not possible for either one.

> 1. Can't the languages just include the functions in them?

This part I am confused with if by this question, you mean **explicit import
 of a function in source file** that programmer is need to do or is it just duplicate of question # 2 , that I already tried to answer.

**Reasons for explicit import :** To have option of multiple implementations of same logic and reduce application program executable size. e.g. a language implemented a function - **sqrt** is such a way that its slow and some other smart programmer wrote same method in more efficient way , wouldn't you like to use second option & not use language provide function ? That can be achieved only if programmer specifies that which sqrt , he / she meant to use.

> 2. Why can't languages already have these functions built in?

Because every piece of software needs to be maintained and continuously upgraded ( as per changing trends in computing ) by a set of people and everybody is constrained of resources esp. in open source environment. So what we do - we try to keep basic language software to minimal so it can easily be maintained and improved upon by core group - X while group - Y , group - Z can take care of non - essential / optional items. That way, scope of a language is limited. You should also know that languages contain lots of features which are rarely used. 
A propriety & rich company like Microsoft might have a different thought process and they might put 1000 dedicated people to their language & try to include everything but most popular languages originated & still live in non - corporate environment.

Other reason is giving flexibility to programmer as already explained. A language which provides you everything and asks you to use only those functions would be very inflexible.

If you put in the complexity of business domains like something specific for Aerospace , something specific for healthcare etc etc , scope gets very unlimited very easily.

Usually, a software is divided into two parts - core part & optional patches ( modules ) to achieve better maintainability , flexibility and reduces software size on need basis.